# WPF MediaElement restart itself?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, mediaelement

I have XAML form which contains (I simplified code to keep transparent):

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               FontSize="20"
               Foreground="Yellow"
               Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}"/>
    ... some others controls ...

    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayer"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.RowSpan="5"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      Loaded="mediaPlayer_Loaded"
                      LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                      MediaEnded="mediaPlayer_MediaEnded"
                      Source="{Binding CurrentAd.Path}" />
</Grid>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
    private void mediaPlayer_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    private void mediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaPlayer.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }
```

As you can see MediaElement shows on fullscreen when CurrentAd object is not null and plays it and starts again when it finishes. Viewmodel contains timer which elapse every 10 seconds and set ErrorMessage property and CurrentAd property (but only when it changed, method Refresh() - listing below).

Method from DataContext:

```
void Refresh()
    {
        try
        {
            Advertisment newAd = AdvertismentManager.GetCurrentAd();
            if (!newAd.Equals(CurrentAd))
                CurrentAd = newAd;
            ....
            ErrorMessage = "";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
```

My problem is that every call of refresh method my video player is restarting itself. It isn't caused by change of binded CurrentAd path. It is caused by assign ErrorMessage variable. I didn't find any similar question on the web and I think it's strange behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that LayoutUpdated event is fired every refresh

Comment: I don't see any problem in your method. It would be better if you shared the complete code of Refresh method and Timer_Elapsed